# React navigation - navigate to another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a navigation stack:

```
<ProfileStack.Navigator>
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{ title: 'Discover'}} />
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileDetailScreen" component={ProfileDetailScreen} options={{ title: 'Profile Detail'}} />
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} options={{ title: 'Messages'}} />
        <MessageStack.Screen 
            name="Chat" 
            component={ChatScreen} 
            options={({ route }) => ({
                title: route.params.thread.username,
                headerRight: () => (
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => alert('ON PRESS SHOULD NAVIGATE TO ProfileDetailScreen')}
                        title="View Profile"
                        color="black"
                    />
                ),
            })} 
        />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
```

When I press the `headerRight` `Button`:

```
onPress={() => alert('ON PRESS SHOULD NAVIGATE TO ProfileDetailScreen')}
```

I need to navigate to:

```
<ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileDetailScreen" component={ProfileDetailScreen} options={{ title: 'Profile Detail'}} />
```

and I need to pass to pass `options={({ route })` to the `ProfileDetailScreen` when I press the `headerRight` button.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/55) helps.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to get the navigation props and use it inside your headerRight:

```
<ProfileStack.Navigator>
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{ title: 'Discover'}} />
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="ProfileDetailScreen" component={ProfileDetailScreen} options={{ title: 'Profile Detail'}} />
        <ProfileStack.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} options={{ title: 'Messages'}} />
        <MessageStack.Screen 
            name="Chat" 
            component={ChatScreen} 
            options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                title: route.params.thread.username,
                headerRight: () => (
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProfileDetailScreen')}
                        title="View Profile"
                        color="black"
                    />
                ),
            })} 
        />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
```